# how to all record from the Angularjs function?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

> Hello developers! i am new on angularjs i want to show the all record after refresh or load the page.. how to use this $scope.sessionlist again when page load

```
$scope.addItem = function (Id) {
        $http.get("/Show/addSngleItem/" + Id).then(function (response) {
            $scope.sessionlist = response.data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
    }
```

> table html data

```
 <table border="1" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CatagoryId</th>
                    <th>Catagory Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="items in sessionlist">
                      <td>{{items.Id}}</td>
                      <td>{{items.Name}}</td>
                      <td><input  type="number" value="{{items.Qty}}" /></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: just call `$scope.addItem(xxx)` at the end of the controller? You need to add more detail to this question.

Comment: Bind $scope.sessionlist in your HTML

Comment: is its possible i only call this $scope.sessionlist data...i know this function $scope.addItem() but i donot want to load full function.

Comment: @Protozoid now you can see the my html code

Comment: Then you shouldn't have to do anything; when `$scope.sessionlist` is set after the HTTP request returns, the view should automatically display it

Comment: I suspect the only potential problem is that response.data isn't a JSON, so do `$scope.sessionlist = JSON.parse(response.data);`

Comment: thanks man! my issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

answering your question ,

when you call your additem function it will get data from server and store the value in sessionlist

the values stored in sessionlist will only be available to a particular scope or time if you reload the page sessionlist will not have the same value which it was there earlier so if you want to have value in sessionlist every time on page load you need to call additem function at end of your controller.

if sessionlist value is static you could store it in local storage and get the value from local storage every time the page load without calling your additem function .

hope this helps